# adding array as parameter to sql query in ruby

Tags: ruby, postgresql, pg

I have an array

```
ziparray = ["95626", "95645", "95837"]
```

I want to pass this to my sql query ,

```
sql = "SELECT * from table_name WHERE code in ($1);"
res1 = conn.exec(sql, [ziparray])
```

It does work for single values.

I am using pg gem and connecting to database using

```
conn = PG.connect()
```

I am using postgres and it doesn't take double quotes . I am assuming that to be the problem.
How to achieve this.

**Update**

I could convert to desired string using

```
str = "'"
str << ziparray.join("','")
str << "'"
#print str
```

But I guess the problem is passing of multiple parameters.

this works -

```
res1 = conn.exec(fipscodesql, ['95626'])
```

But not this

```
res1 = conn.exec(fipscodesql, ['95626', '95625'])
```

and this is exactly what I did when I converted the array to string. I guess this is not the right way to use parameters. 
is there any other way.

Comment: `res1 = conn.exec(sql, [ziparray].join(','))` should work.

Comment: I am trying to convert it to string using `str = ziparray.join("','")` .output I am getting is `95626','95645','95837`. The start and end quotes are missing . How to use join here?

Comment: `[ziparray].map { |zip| "'#{zip}'" }.join(',')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others said, you can't parametrise a whole array. Use this instead:

```
ziparray = ["95626", "95645", "95837"]
zip_placeholders = ziparray.map.with_index(1) { |_, i| "$#{i}" }.join(', ')
sql = "SELECT * from table_name WHERE code in (#{zip_placeholders});"
# => "SELECT * from table_name WHERE code in ($1, $2, $3)"
```

Then you can use the normal parameter binding.

Comment: Your update is not relevant to my answer. I am creating multiple placeholders, each for one value in your array.

Comment: This is the way to go.

Comment: @themaster you invoke the query via `conn.exec(sql, ziparray)` – no need to convert `ziparray` yourself.

Comment: @Stefan yes .. I was kind of confused. This works. Thanks a lot

Comment: There is another question for it https://stackoverflow.com/q/54496161/3483708.

Answer (score 1):

[ziparray].map { |zip| "'#{zip}'" }.join(',')

Answer (score 0):

SQL method "IN" doesn't use array.
So:

```
IN(234) - correct 
IN(234,543) - correct
IN([234,543]) - wrong
```

You can try to convert array to string and pass variable $1 like '95626, 95645, 95837'

Comment: I am trying to convert it to string using `str = ziparray.join("','")` .output I am getting is `95626','95645','95837`. The start and end quotes are missing . How to use join here?

Comment: ["2", "3", "4"].join(',') it is return "2,3,4"

Comment: In my IN its string parameters not int .I need with single quotes each value.

Comment: ["2", "3", "4"].to_s[1..-2] this returned as you want, but I don`t like this way)

Answer (score -1):

If `x` is an array and `x = ['a','b','c']`

```
quotes = (select * from quote in (?), x)
```

- We cannot use this in a SQL parameter
- `x.join(',')` returns `"a,b,c"`. If it is `int` this is not a problem.
- Instead, save this array in a variable and use it in a SQL parameter.

`a = x` and then use `quotes = (select * from quote in (?),a)`