# Ruby PG Gem Using TextEncoder::Array for SELECT WHERE fieldname IN exec_params

Tags: arrays, ruby, postgresql, pg

I need to search for id field from an array.  I'm using the `PG` gem, so I'm thinking I should be using `TextEncoder::Array.new.encode(myarray)` to shove in the qualified list.  The `PostgreSQL` structure is as follows:

```
SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE fieldname IN ('alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie')
```

So my starting array in `Ruby` would be `['alpha', 'charlie', 'bravo']`, so this is my current syntax:

```
a = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'ccharlie']
b = $conn.exec_params( %Q{ SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE fieldname IN ( $1 ) }, [ PG::TextEncoder::Array.new.encode(a) ] )
puts b.inspect
```

`exec_params` obviously takes an array, even it's a single array element.  But using `PG::TextEncoder::Array.new.encode(a)` results in the following structure:

```
"{alpha,bravo,charlie}"
```

...which is an object (.class).  The improper result I'm getting is that there are no records found, which is false.

How can I place a `Ruby` array inside as the first `PG` parameter?

**UPDATE**:

I've been using:

```
...AND NOT (mytable.field = ANY ($6))
```

where `$6` is this:

```
PG::TextEncoder::Array.new(elements_type: PG::TextEncoder::String.new)
```

in a `PG::TypeMapByColumn.new` instance.  The `Ruby` array that's going in there, is valid, holds a value.  It is, in this example, a one-element string in an array, to be used in my SQL statement.  All is good, but it isn't working.  It would help if I actually saw the SQL statement sent to the `db`. Too much is hidden here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer: `...AND NOT hashtag = ANY ($1)...` where $1 is a proper `Ruby` `array`.  It's not actually supported by the `PG gem` people.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question. Using `ANY ($1)` with a PG array type `PG::TextEncoder::Array.new(elements_type: PG::TextEncoder::String.new)` is definitely the best answer here.